# Why is fetch response a single digit

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

*I'm rewriting the question for clarity.*

I have a endpoint that is serving JSON from a Drupal backend. I have a javascript application on the client end of the site from which I'm trying to call `fetch` to get the JSON. However, the `fetch` returns the single digit `3`.

```
fetch('http://irdemo.docksal/my-portal-2/load').then(response => {
 return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Logs out `3`. Here is the Header information from the `load` object in network tab.

```
Request URL:http://irdemo.docksal/my-portal-2/load
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.64.100:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Mon, 09 Oct 2017 13:32:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Request Headers
view parsed
GET /my-portal-2/load HTTP/1.1
Host: irdemo.docksal
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://irdemo.docksal/my-portal-2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

However, if I use the `superagent` library I can get the proper data like this:

```
request('http://irdemo.docksal/my-portal-2/load', (err, response) => {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

I *think* that my endpoint is misconfigured, after all, I'm not using `JSON.parse` to get the response body. I'm not looking for how to fix the backend application, but I'm trying to understand what I should be looking for at the endpoint.

Comment: Your syntax is a little odd, but I just tried it on one of my routes that returns json and it returns just fine. Maybe the issue is in the server?

Comment: try to use response.text() instead of response.json(). What does this return?

Comment: Does it work If you try it like the following? `fetch('/my-url/load', myInit).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: You can remove the `myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');` from your request code, because setting the Content-Type request header for a GET request isn’t going to have any effect other than to trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS request if this is a cross-origin request. And by the way, it’s not a cross-origin request, right? `/my-url/load` is in fact a path and not an absolute URL to an endpoint on a different origin than the origin your frontend JavaScript code is running at?

Comment: @Meier `response.text()` returns the same "3", instead of `3` (string instead of int).

Comment: @sideshowbarker The endpoint is at the same base url as the app. I removed the Content-Type append. I think the next step is to try the request library instead of fetch

Comment: It would help if you go into the Network pane of your browser devtools and reload and copy all the details of the relevant request(s) and response(s) from there — including the HTTP response status code(s) and all the headers and the response body — and paste all that into your question. Otherwise it’s pretty impossible for anybody else here to do much more than guess about what might be going on.

Comment: You’ve checked that what the server’s returning is actually syntactically valid JSON? If you take it and manually run it through a JSON parser outside the browser, it parses without throwing an exception about any syntax errors? And have you tried the request in other browsers and do you observe the same problem in those and do not see any error messages getting logged in the browser devtools console in other browsers?

Comment: your endpoint isn't loading, how are we supposed to know what body it has? Also looks like your response doesn't have a `Content-length` header...